# LinqToTwitter issue connecting with the API in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: asp.net, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I've recently been using LinqToTwitter have incorporated it successfully into a couple of sites. One site is giving me a headache though. It appears to authenticate but as soon as you try and iterate over the collection of tweets returned I get an error:

"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
        {
            CredentialStore = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore
            {
                ConsumerKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterAPIKey"],
                ConsumerSecret = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterSecretKey"],
                AccessToken = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterAccessToken"],
                AccessTokenSecret = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterSecretToken"]
            }
        };

        var ctx = new TwitterContext(auth);
        var mytweets = ctx.Status.Where(t => t.Type == StatusType.User && t.ScreenName == "paulpitchford");

        try
        {
            if (mytweets != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in mytweets)
                {
                    tweets.TweetList.Add(TweetParser.ParseTweet(item.Text));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
        }
    }
```

The error occurs as soon as it hits this line:    foreach (var item in mytweets)

The keys match perfectly to the API given keys and I can't see that I'm doing much wrong. Can anyone suggest where I may be going wrong?

Thank you.

Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ to Twitter is async. This means you need to materialize your query before going into the *foreach* loop, like this:

```
   var mytweets =
       await
       ctx.Status.Where(
           t => t.Type == StatusType.User && 
           t.ScreenName == "paulpitchford")
       .ToListAsync();
```

Notice the *await* on the query and the *ToListAsync* operator. Also, you must add the *async* modifier to *Page_Load*, like this:

```
    protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: Of course! I knew I was missing something. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, I never got this working and left it but now I'm revisiting it, I posted on http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/discussions/588450 fyi. I changed it all to asyn with no avail unfortunately.